# Excel VBA to cut and paste rows below headers based on text in another cell

Tags: loops, row, paste, cut

I am trying to write VBA code to select a row then cut it based on text string "CBL" in col I and paste it under the corresponding header, CABLE RACK AND IRONWORK MATERIAL, selecting row 22 (or maybe a better way to select where to paste the row) to insert the cut row, then doing it again for the next row containing "CBL", pasting it under the previous row and continue doing this until there are no more cells in Col I.  Once complete for cells with text "CBL", I would like to do the same for rows in I containing "FIBER", pasting those rows under the header FIBER MANAGMENT MATERIAL and continue for each until all rows show up under the proper headers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hge1O.png)

I have included what I've tried so far.  The previous version of this did the first row but will not loop until complete.  I mad a change and have broken it since.  I included a snippet of the result I'm looking for.  I am new to this and appreciate the help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NjXC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucG2d.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looking for VBA to search col I (the col with CBL, RCK & IRONWORK; FIBER DUCT; RELAY RACK; etc)  then cut the row and paste it under the corresponding header based on the text in col I.  So, when it sees the text string "CBL" in col I, it would cut row 7 and insert cut row at row 2, then it would see the next one at row 8 then paste it below the previous until it runs out of rows with text string "CBL" in row I.  Then it would do the same for test string "FIBER" in col I and paste it under the Fiber Management Material row, then RELAY Rack items under the Relay Rack Material header, etc.

Comment: Looking to have it cut the rows with text string "CBL" in col I and paste them under the Cable Rack and Ironwork Material header, then do the same with rows with text string "FIBER" in col I, pasting them under the Fiber Management Material header, etc.

Comment: Hope this helps.  The 2nd image shows an example of what the final product would look like.